# ionic 3 app buid failing beacuse of after gradle updated

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, cordova-plugins

while iam trying to build my app some gradle updation was done dynamically and after that my build was failed, i searched on my issue but none was ove my error, after that i tried to create a new app and tried to implement app same as i had before, while implementing the new one, i need to install ionic native plugins [fileOpener](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/) and [geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/), so after installing those plugins, my build was failing with below error..

```
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\midhun\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\056084560d1bc05d95277a5df08184ea\res\values\values.xml:246:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\midhun\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\056084560d1bc05d95277a5df08184ea\res\values\values.xml:246:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

D:\Tineri-v3\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:223: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

D:\Tineri-v3\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:223: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
 FAILED
37 actionable tasks: 37 executed
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
(node:8656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\midhun\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\056084560d1bc05d95277a5df08184ea\res\values\values.xml:246:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\midhun\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\056084560d1bc05d95277a5df08184ea\res\values\values.xml:246:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

D:\Tineri-v3\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:223: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
D:\Tineri-v3\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:223: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
(node:8656) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

while iam searching on it, i got  clue that, because of incompatible of plugin version to my app it is failing, how can i use those plugins in my ionic 3 app, please sought me out of this problem

**here is my ionic info**

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\midhun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Node : v8.9.4
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\midhun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\midhun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

**here is my cordova requirements**

```
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,android-22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,android-21,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,android-20,android-19,Google
Inc.:Google APIs:19,android-18,Google Inc.:Google APIs:18,android-17,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,android-16,Google Inc.:Google APIs:16,android-15,Google Inc.:Google APIs:15,android-14,Google Inc.:Google APIs:14
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to change this file:
platforms/android/project.properties

Instead of "cordova.system.library.1:....v4.0" you should use "cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"

Comment: I had the same problem today. Changing this will fix it but it's not a pretty solution.

Comment: iam having `target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.+
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+` @Humberto de Carvalho

Comment: i have to change for every line which is having lessthan the v4:27 ....? @Humberto de Carvalho

Answer (score 0):

try this command to build an apk for android:

> ionic cordova build android

for more information for this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

Comment: i use the same command `ionic cordova build android` every time to build my app, and also i tried to remove the android platform and again added, but still the problem is same @jorghe94

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but this cordova plugin will do the job for you. The accepted answer didn't help for me, since I'm using a build server.

```
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release
```